# How to include a manifest.json file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have following html code in a view whose layout is false.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Jquery is being loaded but not the manifest.json, when I view page source and look at them I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/manifest.json"
```

Even though I have included manifest.json inside the javascripts folder inside assets folder.

I also tried

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "manifest.json" %>
```

but that didn't work either..and that get routes error
I tried

```
<%= manifest_link_tag "manifest" %>
```

Again that didn't work out, gave error :

```
undefined method `manifest_link_tag'
```

I also added the manifest.json inside **initializers/assets.rb** but still no luck!!

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to include it like [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path):

```
<link rel="manifest" href="<%= asset_path 'manifest.json' %>">
```

Comment: A detail... For it's works when put manifest.json on /assets/javascript path

Answer (score 6):

My solution is:

```
= tag(:link, rel: 'manifest', href: some_path)
```

or

```
= tag(:link, rel: 'manifest', href: asset_path('manifest.json'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 7, and a slightly more comprehensive and multiple-device friendly approach for both a manifest file and some favicons, I used this site to create my favicons: https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/. It gives you a bunch of different sorts of favicon, plus a site manifest file. In Rails 7, I copied all the files it generated into `/app/assets/images` and put this in `application.html.erb`

```
<%= tag(:link, rel: 'apple-touch-icon', sizes: '180x180', href: asset_path('apple-touch-icon.png')) %>
<%= tag(:link, rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', sizes: '32x32', href: asset_path('favicon-32x32.png')) %>
<%= tag(:link, rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', sizes: '16x16', href: asset_path('favicon-16x16.png')) %>
<%= tag(:link, rel: 'manifest', href: asset_path('site.webmanifest')) %>
```

The last line here is the key one for the manifest file (but this manifest file contains useful stuff about the favicons)